# Firebase app give error "Uncaught TypeError: firebase.store is not a function" although I imported firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am new in firebase.I created app that connect to database and create new id in it.

```
const db = firebase.store();
```

my db variable is not reachable.[image]

Comment: In the future please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is no product names `store()` in Firebase.

If you're looking for Firestore (for storing documents with fields and values), use `firebase.firestore()`.

If you're looking for Cloud Storage for Firebase (so for storing unstructured files), use `firebase.storage()`.